# Port 80 Issues with XAMPP Apache

Tags: apache, web, server, xampp

It worked fine at first, but then it kept giving me the error that port 80 was blocked.

I attempted to reconfigure it to port 8080, changed 334 to 3344 yet it didn't work. Restarted by device, uninstalled and installed both apache and XAMPP, nothing worked. I went into my services panel, and everytime I stopped apache there and tried to start it om tje XAMPP program it would give me the same error, yet would be running in services?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  You do not provide enough information to provide an answer.  Only educated guesses.  To know what process is using port 80, run `netstat -anp | grep LISTEN | grep 80`.  You will get the process id and you can check what process that is.  Debug from this point.

Comment: Instead of changing your port number from 80 to any other number, try to identify what application is using it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77028983/my-laptop-is-having-issues-starting-apache-on-the-xampp-control-panel-i-changed/77434525#77434525